# Linksys Cisco SPS2024 Reset to factory defaults

Tags: networking, switch

I have just purchased a second hand Linksys SPS2024 and I don't have any details about the configuration on it i.e. I have no console credentials, no web GUI credentials, no idea what the IP address is. I've tried probing for an IP address using NMap but no luck.  I can log in using HyperTerminal and reset the password which allows me to run some commands. I have been trying to run some of the [commands listed here](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/metro/csbpgss/sps/cli/guide/SPS_CLI_RG_OL-18485-01b.pdf) but for the vast majority I get "% Unrecognized Command".

Basically all I want is to reset it to factory defaults so that I can assign an IP on 192.168.1.1-254 range for now, so that I can access the Web GUI and configure it from there.

Comment: Were you able to enter Global Configuration mode or Interface Configuration mode (highest privilege)?

Comment: Yes I am able to access the Global configuration mode.  Just trying to figure out how to remove all the existing VLAN config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve my problem I had to do the following steps

1. Hit 'esc' on startup and select option 3 to bypass the current
   password requirements for the admin user.
2. Enter Privileged EXEC Mode
   by running command `enable` then enter Global Configuration mode
   using command `enable`
3. Delete startup config: `delete startup-config`
4. Reboot then assign a password to admin user: `username admin password alansmith`
5. Enable all Ethernet ports: `interface range ethernet all` then run - `no shutdown`
6. For some reason the GUI was defaulting to 192.168.1.254 for VLAN 1 so I
   assigned it a static IP: `int vlan 1` -> `ip address 192.168.1.20
   255.255.255.0`

   The admin GUI is now accessible from 192.168.1.20 using username admin and the password I assigned.  The GUI only
   seems to work properly using Internet Explorer in compatibility
   mode.

Answer (score 0):

According to the following PDF docs, the Default IP is assigned dynamically:
[SPS208G/SPS224G4/SPS2024 Ethernet Switches](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/metro/csbpgss/sps/administration/guide/Cisco_SPS208G224G4_UG_OL-18486-01.pdf)

> By default, the IP address of the device is assigned dynamically, although it can be changed to a static IP address by an administrator

Perhaps it's not getting an IP if you don't have a DHCP server.

It's normally possible to change the device config using via the Console but looks as though you need to enter Global Configuration mode or Interface Configuration mode (highest privilege)

The docs for the Command Line Interface (you also linked) should enable you to do so:
[SPS208G/SPS224G4/SPS2024 Ethernet Switches Command Line Interface](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/metro/csbpgss/sps/cli/guide/SPS_CLI_RG_OL-18485-01b.pdf)

Comment: So I have enabled dhcp autoconfig using the Global Configuration mode but still no IP address is being assigned.  The dhcp server is working as expected so not sure whats up with it